# Peoplecode function not working

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

I am using Peoplecode which is a Peoplesoft coding language.

I am trying to access JUST the `'message text'` from a message catalog.

It pulls the correct number `7373` when I use the same code on another page.

But in this instance it returns the message

> 'GetMessageText: No default message. (2012,2012)'.

Here is the code I am using..

```
   &cur_year = Year(%Date);
   &MsgNum = MsgGetText(2012, 2012, "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it can't find the message (2012,2012). You have to specify the correct message set and message number to retrieve from the message catalog.

Look here:
[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28394_01/pt852pbh1/eng/psbooks/tpcl/book.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm%2337ee99c9453fb39_ef90c_10c791ddc07__3cd3](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28394_01/pt852pbh1/eng/psbooks/tpcl/book.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm#37ee99c9453fb39_ef90c_10c791ddc07__3cd3)